# Continuous moderator and an interaction term with a latent variable in lavaan

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am a rather new user of lavaan and have been trying to build a moderator model with a continuous moderator and an interaction term with a latent variable. I would like to hear your feedback on my code and especially **whether my approach seems appropriate regarding adding the interaction term afterwards** (as it requires saving the latent variable in the data frame). Just to give a short description of my study: I investigate the relationship between stress and burnout, and whether social support moderates this association. Unfortunately, I don’t have the actual data yet, so I cannot give information on the possible warning/error messages.

```
#Creating the centered moderator variable SSMCOVID.c
Dataset$SSMCOVID.c <- scale(Dataset$SSMCOVID, scale = FALSE)

#Setting up the measurement model
RQ3 <- '
#Creating the independent TsM variable:
TsM =~ 1*SsM3mo + 1*SsM12mo + 1*SsM4y + 1*SsM4.5y

# Stress-burnout (independent-dependent):
PBAMCOVID ~ b1*TsM

#Support-burnout (moderator-dependent):
PBAMCOVID ~ b2*SSMCOVID.c '

fit.3 <- sem(RQ3, data = Dataset, estimator = 'MLR', missing = 'ML')
summary(fit.3, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE)

#Extracting the predicted values of the model and adding them to the dataframe
data <- data.frame(Dataset, predict(fit.3))

#Creating a new variable with the interaction (note: dplyr package needed!)
data <- data %>%
              mutate(TsM_x_SSMCOVID.c = TsM * SSMCOVID.c)
              
#Testing the predefined interaction (moderation):
Moderation <- ' PBAMCOVID ~ b3*TsM_x_SSMCOVID.c '

fit.Mod <- sem(Moderation, data = data, estimator = 'MLR', missing = 'ML')
summary(fit.Mod, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
```

Comment: What is SSMCOVID? Is it a latent or a manifest variable?

Comment: It's a manifest variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide actual data, I will produce an example using the HolzingerSwineford1939 data frame. The library `semTools` has a function to make products of indicators using no centering, mean centering, double-mean centering, or residual centering:

```r
df_mod <- indProd(data = HolzingerSwineford1939, #create a new data.frame with the interaction indicators
                  var1 = paste0("x",c(1:3)), #interaction indicators from the first latent
                  var2 = paste0("x",c(4:6)), #interaction indicators from the second latent
                  match = T, #use match-paired approach (it produces the product of the first indicators of each variable, the product of the second indicator of each latent variable...
                  meanC = T, # mean centering the main effect indicator before making the products
                  residualC = T, #residual centering the products by the main effect indicators
                  doubleMC = T) #centering the resulting products

head(df_mod[,(ncol(df_mod)-2):ncol(df_mod)]) #check the last three columns of the new data.frame


model_latent_mod <- "
latent_mod =~  
x1.x4+
x2.x5+
x3.x6"

fit_lat_mod <- cfa(model = model_latent_mod, data = df_mod) #run your latent interaction measurement model
summary(object = fit_lat_mod, std=T, fit.m=T) #check the summary
```

Then you just add this measurement model to your structural model. This approach is useful to produce interaction among latent variables, which I believe should be your case.

If you want interaction between a latent variable and a manifest variable:

```r
model_latent_manifest_inter <- "
latent_mod =~  
x1
x2
x3

ageyr ~latent_mod:x4
"

fit_lat_mod <- sem(model = model_latent_manifest_inter, data = HolzingerSwineford1939) #run your latent interaction measurement model
summary(object = fit_lat_mod, std=T, fit.m=T) #check the summary
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! The latent variable that I presented in the example above is actually a simplified version of the actual latent variable. The actual latent variable is a three level model (one example of a TSO model can be found in  Jeffrey A. Ciesla, David A. Cole & James H. Steiger (2007) Extending the
Trait–State–Occasion Model: How Important Is Within-Wave Measurement Equivalence?, Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 14:1, 77-97, DOI: 10.1080/10705510709336737). Can I use the approach that you presented also with this kind of latent variables?

Comment: Yes, you can... choose three indicators from each of the two latent variables and use them in the `var1` and `var2` arguments. This is the approach to produce a latent interaction (using two latent variables).

Comment: And does this also fit when the interaction is between a latent and an observed variable?

Comment: In that case, is even simpler... `latentvariable:indicator`, use the `:` operator. I adapted my answer.

Comment: Great, that is indeed much simpler! I had for some reason thought that it's not possible to make an interaction term this way in lavaan. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Good to know. If my answer solved your question, please mark it as solved and upvote if do you think it deserves to upvoted.

Comment: After some more reading, I still get the understanding that in lavaan the '' : " operator can only be used with observed variables, which would mean that I cannot use it, since the interaction is between a latent and an observed variable in my analysis.

Comment: As I mentioned, in such a situation you can use the first approach (i.e., `indProd` function). If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as solved.